# How to debug pandas groupby apply function

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I'm trying to understand the function that is written by my ex-colleague.

```
def generate_df(group):  
    date_str = str(group['CallerLocal_Date'].iloc[-1]) + ' {0}:00:00'
    # some other functions
    return something

enrich_df = df.groupby(['LeadNumber', 'CallerLocal_Date'], as_index=False).apply(generate_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I couldn't fully understand the function above so I was trying to groupby and actually see what `date_str = str(group['CallerLocal_Date'].iloc[-1]) + ' {0}:00:00'` line does.

`df` looks like this

```
        LeadNumber             CallerLocal_Date  Caller_TimeZone
0      7-OH4UMXXL5                   2017-09-13  America/Chicago
1      7-OL4ZHUF47                   2017-09-26  America/Chicago
2      7-OL4ZHUF47                   2017-09-26  America/Chicago
3      7-OHMFNFFC2                   2017-09-13  America/Chicago
4      7-OHMFNFFC2                   2017-09-12  America/Chicago
5      7-OGBMIPIIN                   2017-09-11  America/Chicago
6      7-OGBMIPIIN                   2017-09-07  America/Chicago
7      7-OETJOA7O6                   2017-09-01  America/Chicago
8      7-OETJOA7O6                   2017-09-06  America/Chicago
9      7-OILTU4T5O                   2017-09-18  America/Chicago
10     7-OGJHKCJFZ                   2017-09-07  America/Chicago
```

so I defined

```
group = df.groupby(['LeadNumber', 'CallerLocal_Date'], as_index=False)
```

and call

```
date_str = str(group['CallerLocal_Date'].iloc[-1]) + ' {0}:00:00'
```

Then I got

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'iloc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Can someone point me to how to debug the groupby object, without using `apply` function?

Comment: Add three print statements in inside your generate_df function   `print(type(group))`, `print(group)` and `print('\n')`, this will let you look exactly what is getting passed.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
groups = df.groupby(['LeadNumber', 'CallerLocal_Date'], as_index=False)
group = groups.get_group(list(groups.groups)[0])
```

Then you can run your code line by line:

```
date_str = str(group['CallerLocal_Date'].iloc[-1]) + ' {0}:00:00'
```

Comment: feels like `pandas` should have a more elegant way to do this. May be an argument like `df.groupby(.., debug=True, ..)`